# How to run sikuli scripts with python?

Tags: python, importerror, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

```
from sikuli.Sikuli import *
click("1519208908961.png")
sleep(5)
click("1519209904771.png")
sleep(20)
click("1519209975577.png")
sleep(120)
find("1519211685466.png")
doubleClick("1519211719891.png")
click("1519212466623.png")
sleep(180)
```

I have a Sikuli script like this. But while running in Python IDLE

it is throwing

```
Trackback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\sxe10\AutoInstall.sikuli\AutoInstall.py", line 1, in <module>
        from sikuli.Sikuli import *

    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sikuli-0.1-py2.7-win32.egg\sikuli\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from sikuli import *

      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sikuli-0.1-py2.7-win32.egg\sikuli\sikuli.py", line 15, in <module>
        from jnius import autoclass

     File "c:\users\sxe10\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-g88cag\jnius-1.1.dev0-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\jnius\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>

     File "c:\users\sxe10\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-g88cag\jnius-1.1.dev0-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\jnius\jnius.py", line 7, in <module>

    File "c:\users\sxe10\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-g88cag\jnius-1.1.dev0-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\jnius\jnius.py", line 6, in _bootstrap__
```

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be
>   found.

Please help to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: this is jython which you are importing have you started jar as a service....

Comment: I think it's not

Comment: How were you launching your Sikuli script?  The way we were doing with version 1.1.1 was `java -Dsikuli.Debug=-2 -cp sikulix.jar org.python.util.jython my_script.py`. We will have to add the jython jar in version 1.1.4.